# How do I determine frida-server version on device?

Tags: adb, magisk

I did not push and  frida-server manually on device but I can connect to rooted device with frida-ps and adb enabled. I have magisk and shamiko and Lsposed. Some post suggests that magisk has its own version of frida installed. How do I get details of that installation with frida-tools on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that it's possible to emulate the list of processes using `frida-ps -U` *without* running `frida-server` on the android device. Details:

[Why you make frida-ps -U return all the process even if the frida-server is not running on the device ?](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/1836)

However you'll need frida server (or frida gadget) if you want to instrument an app

That clarifies that non of my magisk modules run frida and the only server are the ones that I install myself and the frida-boot magisk module (which I did not install either)

Answer (score 1):

Magisk does not include Frida, but there is a Magisk module available which includes frida-server and starts it automatically at boot time.

I don't know if there is a way to check the frida-server version e.g. within a Frida script but you can use the traditional way via `adb shell`:

- Open a new shell via `adb shell`
- Get root permissions by executing `su`
- Check the path of a running frida-server instance via ps: `ps -Af | grep frida-server`
- Use the full path of `frida-server` shown in the ps output and execute it with the `--version` option